# Executing Join with SQL Window Functions

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to eliminate all common instances of 2 column values, on a Redshift db.
I've got as far as writing 2 SELECT statements which both work independently, but have errors when trying to join them, or even simply when running the 1 after the other.

Here they are

```
select * 

from
(SELECT distinct management_firm_id ,
                LISTAGG(city,',')
                WITHIN GROUP (Order by city)
                OVER (PARTITION BY ci.management_firm_id) as FlatCity
)                AS ci

JOIN

(SELECT distinct management_firm_id , 
                 LISTAGG(sub_market,',')
                 WITHIN GROUP (Order by sub_market)
                 OVER (PARTITION BY sm.management_firm_id) AS flatSubMarket
                 from (SELECT distinct management_firm_id,sub_market from tableau_prep.dom_complete_manager_info) AS sm)

on ci.management_firm_id = sm.management_firm_id
```

the message I'm getting is below:

An error occurred when executing the SQL command:

```
select * 

from
(SELECT distinct management_firm_id ,
                LISTAGG(city,',')
                WITHIN GROUP (Order by city)
                O...

ERROR: syntax error at or near "from"
  Position: 222

)               from (SELECT distinct management_firm_id,city from tableau_prep.dom_complete_manager_info) AS ci
            ^
```

1 statement failed.

I would like to get 3 columns: 1 fund_manager_id 2 secondary asset 3 sub-market

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you don't have a FROM clause in your first subquery.

```
... (SELECT distinct management_firm_id , LISTAGG(city,',') WITHIN GROUP (Order by city) OVER (PARTITION BY ci.management_firm_id) as FlatCity ) AS ci
```

This is likely what the problem.

Also, you are using the LISTAGG() window function and it looks like you want the LISTAGG() aggregate function.  Yes there are 2 LISTAGG() functions.  You shouldn't need DISTINCT or OVER but will have GROUP BY. This will make your code clearer and run faster.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html